# Jekyll Bootstrap not importing glyphicons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I just started using Jekyll today and so far I like it.

I'm using one of the default themes (titled simply `bootstrap-3`) and it seems to compile fine, in terms of file structure.

However, when I run it on my local server (or on github.io), some files are missing, notably the glyphicon fonts that come default with Bootstrap.

The `fonts` folder exists in both the `_site/assets` directory as well as the external `assets` directory, and as far as I knew, the contents of the `_site` directory were what got served on the server.

However, when I use the Google Dev Tools to look for the assets, I can't find the fonts at all. The CSS is generated fine, but the fonts are not.

Interestingly enough, when I use another theme (like `the-project`) the fonts are loaded fine.

Glyphicons exist in my `bootstrap.min.css`, the only thing I can think of is that the `url()` code is wrong:

`src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')` is in my `bootstrap.css`, and my file structure is set up such that the parent folder does contain the `fonts` folder.

Here is my directory tree:

```
bootstrap-3
├── bootstrap
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   └── bootstrap.theme.min.css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│   └── js
│       └── bootstrap.min.js
└── css
    └── style.css
```

And [here is my output site](http://abustamam.github.io/contact/), I'm wanting to put a glyphicon in the `submit` button of the contact page (which isn't visible from the main site because I haven't focused on UI yet).

Interestingly enough, when I put a glyphicon somewhere *not* in the button, it will display.

EDIT: Wow, accidentally put a `>` in the class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to http://getbootstrap.com and watch the network inspector you will not see any font loaded. But if you go to http://getbootstrap.com/components/, you will see them jump in the browser.

The browser loads fonts only if it needs them (if you use *glyphicon-xxx* styles). This is called **Lazy loading** and it avoids loading unnecessary resources.

**Edit** : If you don't use glyphicons in you site they're not loaded. The base Jekyll Bootstrap doesn't use glyphicons.

Try to add  in one of your files (eg : pages.html) or a markdown equivalent in index.md and you will see fonts loading in you network inspector.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but my stylesheets are calling for said fonts in `@font-face`. Am I missing something in my `bootstrap.css`? I don't think I would be since it's what came default but ya never know.

Comment: But that's the thing, I am using glyphicons. I have an empty `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-send'>` tag and I double checked to make sure that the class existed in `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: So, I need to see your base code or the resulting build.

Comment: Ah, actually I see my error. My `span` read this: `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-send>'></span>`. The error was that a carat made it into the classname. Wow. Thanks David!